# Ubuntu 15.10 webcam upside down google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, skype, webcam

I am quiet new in Ubuntu world. I found lots of solutions for skype flipped image. Actually lots of them are not working properly or you have to do same process again and again.

My problem is about chrome. In chrome when I need to take photo, it shows flipped. And chrome - 64 bit as you know, because of that libv4l is not working for chrome.

Comment: Have you checked to see that the webcam is oriented properly?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it will not work with Chrome until Google fix their Linux version. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749038/ubuntu-15-10-webcam-flipped-chrome/814523#814523) for better explanation.